# Scraping in no GUI env using selenium headless browser

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Currently testing my project in an environment without GUI,it is written in python in order to scrap data from facebook marketplace using selenium package and headless browser, link to the project: https://github.com/lokman-sassi/FMP-Scraper-with-Selenium , for that I'm using ubuntu 22.04 as subsystem in windows (only terminal).
The problem is, when i read a documentation about selenium, it says that i don't need the browser installed at all on my computer to work with, he will use only the driver of the browser, but i was surprised that while executing my file in ubuntu, he returned to me an error saying that i don't have chrome installed ! which is contrary to the documentation, how can i fix that issue, cause i want to scrap without the need to the browser installed on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) operates in a headless environment (meaning it does not require a graphical user interface), it still requires the browser binary (e.g., [Chrome](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/), Firefox) to be installed on your system. The headless mode allows Selenium to run the browser in the background without popping up a window.

```bash
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   +------------------------+
| Your Python Code  |-->| Selenium Package  |-->| Headless Browser       |
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   + (e.g., Chrome/Firefox) |
                                      ^         +------------------------+
                                      |                  
                                Requires Browser
                                 Binary to Run
```

Install the browser binary on your system, even though you are running it in headless mode.

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wget
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

After installing Chrome, make sure your Selenium script is correctly configured to use Chrome in headless mode.  *
(Note: I assume Selenium 4+, [using a Service object, and executable_path has been deprecated](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#python-1))

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True  # Enable headless mode

# Create a Service object, pointing to the path of chromedriver
service = ChromeService(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')

# Initialize the Chrome driver with the service and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/marketplace")
# Your scraping logic here
```